# Does Fox News have a history of being skeptical of climate change science?

Tags: united-states, media, climate-change

Does Fox News have a history of being skeptical of or minimizing the effects of global warming?

If yes, does this reflect the Republican view of the phenomenon or is it specific to Fox News?

Comment: I think this question really should be "Why has the debate over global warming usually always been split down conservative/liberal lines". It has nothing to do with any one entity, be it a news organization, political figurehead, etc. I've always asked this question myself over the years and am curious as to the answer.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin look here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/why-is-denying-global-warming-associated-with-conservatives

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question seems to have a well-known answer, at least in liberal quarters, [namely that](https://www.citizen.org/news/climate-change-denial-dominates-86-of-fox-news-climate-segments/)

> Climate denial claims dominated 86% of climate change segments on Fox News this year, according to a new Public Citizen analysis.

This should not come as a big surprise since the views expressed on Fox News on this matter are [consistent](https://thebulletin.org/2019/05/fox-news-made-the-us-a-hotbed-of-climate-denial-kids-are-the-cure/) with those of their audience

> Another recent survey found that Republicans who watch Fox News are more than twice as likely to deny human-caused climate change than Republican non-viewers, and 62 percent of Republicans watch Fox News. Consistent with the demographic breakdown of American climate denial, Fox News viewers are overwhelmingly old and white, as are climate deniers.

These are quick finds from journalistic sources. There are probably peer-reviewed publications that find similarly, but I don't have time to search those right now.

Comment: Public Citizen, Inc. is a liberal 501(c)(4) lobbying and advocacy organization created by left-wing activist and former Green Party presidential candidate Ralph Nader  https://www.influencewatch.org/non-profit/public-citizen/

Comment: @K Dog: So?  Information should be judged on its validity, not its source.